# How to know if there is a changes in a specific textbox, the textbox is dynamically created in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox

I want to put a value in other dynamically created textbox if there is a changes in a specific textbox that was also dynamically created. How could I possibly do this?

this is how i created the textbox:

```
for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
        {
            TextBox txt = new TextBox();
            txt.Name = dt.Rows[x]["field_name"].ToString();
    txt.Text = txt.Name;
            txt.Width = 200;
            var margintx = txt.Margin;
            margintx.Bottom = 5;
            txt.Margin = margintx;

            flowLayoutPanelText.Controls.Add(txt);
        }
```

Here is the output of it:

[image]

Example if I put a value to the Mag Data, it will also pass the value to Card Number and Exp Date. How could I possibly do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can dynamically add an event handler to your Dynamic `TextBox's` TextChanged Event and since you are also using your `Field` Names as your `TextBox` Name you can cast your events sender object to determine which `TextBox` was changed.

```
for (int x = 0; x < dt.Rows.Count; x++)
{
    TextBox txt = new TextBox();
    txt.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txt_TextChanged);
    txt.Name = dt.Rows[x]["field_name"].ToString();
    txt.Text = txt.Name;
    txt.Width = 200;
    var margintx = txt.Margin;
    margintx.Bottom = 5;
    txt.Margin = margintx;
    flowLayoutPanelText.Controls.Add(txt);
}

void txt_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    TextBox tb = (TextBox)sender;
    if (tb.Name == "Mag Data")
    {
        //Do Stuff Here
    }
}
```

---

The issue that you are having is that your `Name` Property is not accessable as a `TextBox` i.e you can not do "Card Number".Text you will need to search the Control Collection for the TextBox named "Card Number" you can use the [Controls.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.find%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) Method to do so.

i.e.

```
if (tb.Name == "Mag Data")
{
    Control[] cntrl = Controls.Find("Card Number", true);
    if (cntrl.Length != 0)
    {
        ((TextBox)cntrl[0]).Text = tb.Text;
    }
}
```

Comment: 'event handler' not 'event'

Comment: btw, in passing the value to another textbox?

Comment: @GrayFullBuster If I understand what you are asking you have access to the Value in the tb.Text's property and you can pass it to which ever textbox you want.

Comment: @MarkHall, just an example whatever I type in the textbox where name is "Mag Data" will be displayed in another textbox like "Card Number" or etc. How to do that? still confused. Thanks!

Comment: @GrayFullBuster I added an additional example, since your are creating your controls dynamically you will need to Find them in your Form, the added code does that.

Answer (score 2):

Add an event handler to the textbox:

```
txt.TextChanged += (sender, args) => {
    // Logic to update other textboxes
};
```